# delete first 2 rows of a flat file using command line in execute process task

Tags: cmd, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a flat file in my desktop which I am trying to load into a table using SSIS. However, the first 2 rows of the flat file are not required. I am using command line in execute process task in SSIS to do the same -
/C more +2 file.txt > new_file.txt
However, it keeps showing error.

Comment: which error?  `'/C'  is not recognized as an .... command`? Think about it...

Comment: well, what argument in execute process task in ssis will delete the first 2 rows of a flat file (.csv in this case)